# Import all XML to SQL?

Tags: sql, xml

This `c.value('(rep_Operation/@OpNumber)[1]'` only insert in the table the first record of the xml file, how can i do to insert the rest of the file

```sql
SELECT 
    CAST(LEFT(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/@ReadingDate)[1]', 'varchar(100)'), 10) AS date) AS data1,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/@PostalCode)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS int) AS Cliente,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/WaterMeterData/@Index)[1]', 'decimal(18, 2)') AS int) AS Leitura
FROM 
    XmlFile 
CROSS APPLY 
    xmlData.nodes('(/ActarisEasyRoutes/Route/RouteData/Customers)') AS t(c)
UNION
SELECT 
    CAST(LEFT(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/@ReadingDate)[2]', 'varchar(100)'), 10) AS date) AS data1,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/@PostalCode)[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS int) AS Cliente,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/WaterMeterData/@Index)[2]', 'decimal(18, 2)') AS int) AS Leitura
FROM 
    XmlFile 
CROSS APPLY 
    xmlData.nodes('(/ActarisEasyRoutes/Route/RouteData/Customers)') AS t(c)
```

XML:

Comment: Probably better to use Powershell and insert the data to SQL.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: We need to see your XML. Please add it to your question.