# Import all XML into SQL

Tags: sql, xml

This `c.value('(rep_Operation/@OpNumber)[1]'` only insert in the table the first record of the xml file, how can I do to insert the rest of the file:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ActarisEasyRoutes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="Route" XMLVersion="v2.3">
    <Route ID="1" Name="Route" Code="Route1" Password="" Message="">
        <RouteSettings>
            <RouteWaterMeterSettings ConsumptionControlFlag="2" MaxConsumption1="0" MaxConsumption2="0" MaxConsumption3="0" MaxConsumption4="0" Tolerance1="0" Tolerance2="0" Tolerance3="0" Tolerance4="0" Tolerance5="0" />
            <RouteHeatMeterSettings ConsumptionControlFlag="2" MaxConsumption1="0" MaxConsumption2="0" MaxConsumption3="0" MaxConsumption4="0" Tolerance1="0" Tolerance2="0" Tolerance3="0" Tolerance4="0" Tolerance5="0" DefaultFirstFrame="1" DefaultSecondFrame="2" />
            <RouteGasMeterSettings ConsumptionControlFlag="2" MaxConsumption1="0" MaxConsumption2="0" MaxConsumption3="0" MaxConsumption4="0" Tolerance1="0" Tolerance2="0" Tolerance3="0" Tolerance4="0" Tolerance5="0" CalorificFactor="0.0000" />
        </RouteSettings>
    <RouteData>
    <Customers>
        <Customer ID="1" BillingCode="" FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL 276 P5 ESQ TR" LastName="" Address="FLAVIA ARAUJO AFONSO" PostalCode="1337602" City="" Created="false" Modified="false">
          <Meters>
              <WaterMeter ID="1" BillingCode="" ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:07" ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1" ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8" EnergyType="0" UnitType="0" SerialNumber="12LA066872" ReadSerialNumber="12LA066872" SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage="" FileNumber="0" Created="false" Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                  <WaterMeterData Index="326.629" IndexCheck="0" ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1" ConsumptionTolerance="0" ConsumptionMin="0" ConsumptionMax="0" />
              </WaterMeter>
          </Meters>
      </Customer>
      <Customer ID="2" BillingCode="" FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P1 DRT FR" LastName="" Address="LILIANA SOFIA ESTEVES DA SILVA" PostalCode="1319337" City="" Created="false" Modified="false">
          <Meters>
              <WaterMeter ID="2" BillingCode="" ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:07" ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1" ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8" EnergyType="0" UnitType="0" SerialNumber="12LA056530" ReadSerialNumber="12LA056530" SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage="" FileNumber="1" Created="false"  Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                  <WaterMeterData Index="538.157" IndexCheck="0" ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1" ConsumptionTolerance="0" ConsumptionMin="0" ConsumptionMax="0" />
              </WaterMeter>
          </Meters>
      </Customer>
      <Customer ID="3" BillingCode="" FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P1 DRT TR" LastName="" Address="EDUARDO AUGUSTO SILVA RAMOS" PostalCode="442569" City="" Created="false" Modified="false">
          <Meters>
              <WaterMeter ID="3" BillingCode="" ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:07" ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1" ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8" EnergyType="0" UnitType="0" SerialNumber="12LA056557" ReadSerialNumber="12LA056557" SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage="" FileNumber="2" Created="false" Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                  <WaterMeterData Index="213.476" IndexCheck="0" ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1" ConsumptionTolerance="0" ConsumptionMin="0" ConsumptionMax="0" />
              </WaterMeter>
          </Meters>
      </Customer>
      <Customer ID="4" BillingCode="" FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P1 ESQ" LastName="" Address="ALFREDO MARTINS SOARES" PostalCode="526193" City="" Created="false" Modified="false">
          <Meters>
              <WaterMeter ID="4" BillingCode="" ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:08" ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1" ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8" EnergyType="0" UnitType="0" SerialNumber="12LA056553" ReadSerialNumber="12LA056553" SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage="" FileNumber="3" Created="false" Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                  <WaterMeterData Index="151.356" IndexCheck="0" ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1" ConsumptionTolerance="0" ConsumptionMin="0" ConsumptionMax="0" />
              </WaterMeter>
          </Meters>
      </Customer>
      <Customer ID="5" BillingCode="" FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P2 DRT FR" LastName="" Address="ALICE MELO COSTA" PostalCode="486647" City="" Created="false" Modified="false">
          <Meters>
              <WaterMeter ID="5" BillingCode="" ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:08" ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1" ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8" EnergyType="0" UnitType="0" SerialNumber="12LA056712" ReadSerialNumber="12LA056712" SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage="" FileNumber="4" Created="false" Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                  <WaterMeterData Index="344.635" IndexCheck="0" ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1" ConsumptionTolerance="0" ConsumptionMin="0" ConsumptionMax="0" />
              </WaterMeter>
          </Meters>
      </Customer>
      <!-- and so on .... many more customers ...... ->
      </RouteData>
    </Route>
</ActarisEasyRoutes>
```

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(LEFT(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/@ReadingDate)[1]', 'varchar(100)'), 10) AS date) AS data1,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/@PostalCode)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS int) AS Cliente,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/WaterMeterData/@Index)[1]', 'decimal(18, 2)') AS int) AS Leitura
FROM 
    XmlFile 
CROSS APPLY 
    xmlData.nodes('(/ActarisEasyRoutes/Route/RouteData/Customers)') AS t(c)

UNION

SELECT 
    CAST(LEFT(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/@ReadingDate)[2]', 'varchar(100)'), 10) AS date) AS data1,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/@PostalCode)[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS int) AS Cliente,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/WaterMeterData/@Index)[2]', 'decimal(18, 2)') AS int) AS Leitura
FROM 
    XmlFile 
CROSS APPLY 
    xmlData.nodes('(/ActarisEasyRoutes/Route/RouteData/Customers)') AS t(c)

SELECT 
    CAST(LEFT(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/@ReadingDate)[1]', 'varchar(100)'), 10) AS date) AS data1,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/@PostalCode)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS int) AS Cliente,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/WaterMeterData/@Index)[1]', 'decimal(18, 2)') AS int) AS Leitura
FROM 
    XmlFile 
CROSS APPLY 
    xmlData.nodes('(/ActarisEasyRoutes/Route/RouteData/Customers)') AS t(c)

UNION

SELECT 
    CAST(LEFT(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/@ReadingDate)[2]', 'varchar(100)'), 10) AS date) AS data1,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/@PostalCode)[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS int) AS Cliente,
    CAST(c.value('(Customer/Meters/WaterMeter/WaterMeterData/@Index)[2]', 'decimal(18, 2)') AS int) AS Leitura
FROM 
    XmlFile 
CROSS APPLY 
    xmlData.nodes('(/ActarisEasyRoutes/Route/RouteData/Customers)') AS t(c)
```

Comment: XML support is **HIGHLY** vendor-specific - which concrete RDBMS is this for? Please add a corresponding product tag

Comment: You already asked the same question earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76677343/import-all-xml-to-sql There is no need to mushroom your questions.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Asset_ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<ActarisEasyRoutes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="Route"
                   XMLVersion="v2.3">
    <Route ID="1" Name="Route" Code="Route1" Password="" Message="">
        <RouteSettings>
            <RouteWaterMeterSettings ConsumptionControlFlag="2"
                                     MaxConsumption1="0" MaxConsumption2="0"
                                     MaxConsumption3="0" MaxConsumption4="0"
                                     Tolerance1="0" Tolerance2="0"
                                     Tolerance3="0" Tolerance4="0"
                                     Tolerance5="0"/>
            <RouteHeatMeterSettings ConsumptionControlFlag="2"
                                    MaxConsumption1="0" MaxConsumption2="0"
                                    MaxConsumption3="0" MaxConsumption4="0"
                                    Tolerance1="0" Tolerance2="0" Tolerance3="0"
                                    Tolerance4="0" Tolerance5="0"
                                    DefaultFirstFrame="1" DefaultSecondFrame="2"/>
            <RouteGasMeterSettings ConsumptionControlFlag="2"
                                   MaxConsumption1="0" MaxConsumption2="0"
                                   MaxConsumption3="0" MaxConsumption4="0"
                                   Tolerance1="0" Tolerance2="0" Tolerance3="0"
                                   Tolerance4="0" Tolerance5="0"
                                   CalorificFactor="0.0000"/>
        </RouteSettings>
        <RouteData>
            <Customers>
                <Customer ID="1" BillingCode=""
                          FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL 276 P5 ESQ TR" LastName=""
                          Address="FLAVIA ARAUJO AFONSO" PostalCode="1337602"
                          City="" Created="false" Modified="false">
                    <Meters>
                        <WaterMeter ID="1" BillingCode=""
                                    ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:07"
                                    ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1"
                                    ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8"
                                    EnergyType="0" UnitType="0"
                                    SerialNumber="12LA066872"
                                    ReadSerialNumber="12LA066872"
                                    SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage=""
                                    FileNumber="0" Created="false"
                                    Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                            <WaterMeterData Index="326.629" IndexCheck="0"
                                            ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1"
                                            ConsumptionTolerance="0"
                                            ConsumptionMin="0"
                                            ConsumptionMax="0"/>
                        </WaterMeter>
                    </Meters>
                </Customer>
                <Customer ID="2" BillingCode=""
                          FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P1 DRT FR"
                          LastName="" Address="LILIANA SOFIA ESTEVES DA SILVA"
                          PostalCode="1319337" City="" Created="false"
                          Modified="false">
                    <Meters>
                        <WaterMeter ID="2" BillingCode=""
                                    ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:07"
                                    ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1"
                                    ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8"
                                    EnergyType="0" UnitType="0"
                                    SerialNumber="12LA056530"
                                    ReadSerialNumber="12LA056530"
                                    SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage=""
                                    FileNumber="1" Created="false"
                                    Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                            <WaterMeterData Index="538.157" IndexCheck="0"
                                            ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1"
                                            ConsumptionTolerance="0"
                                            ConsumptionMin="0"
                                            ConsumptionMax="0"/>
                        </WaterMeter>
                    </Meters>
                </Customer>
                <Customer ID="3" BillingCode=""
                          FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P1 DRT TR"
                          LastName="" Address="EDUARDO AUGUSTO SILVA RAMOS"
                          PostalCode="442569" City="" Created="false"
                          Modified="false">
                    <Meters>
                        <WaterMeter ID="3" BillingCode=""
                                    ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:07"
                                    ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1"
                                    ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8"
                                    EnergyType="0" UnitType="0"
                                    SerialNumber="12LA056557"
                                    ReadSerialNumber="12LA056557"
                                    SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage=""
                                    FileNumber="2" Created="false"
                                    Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                            <WaterMeterData Index="213.476" IndexCheck="0"
                                            ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1"
                                            ConsumptionTolerance="0"
                                            ConsumptionMin="0"
                                            ConsumptionMax="0"/>
                        </WaterMeter>
                    </Meters>
                </Customer>
                <Customer ID="4" BillingCode=""
                          FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P1 ESQ" LastName=""
                          Address="ALFREDO MARTINS SOARES" PostalCode="526193"
                          City="" Created="false" Modified="false">
                    <Meters>
                        <WaterMeter ID="4" BillingCode=""
                                    ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:08"
                                    ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1"
                                    ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8"
                                    EnergyType="0" UnitType="0"
                                    SerialNumber="12LA056553"
                                    ReadSerialNumber="12LA056553"
                                    SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage=""
                                    FileNumber="3" Created="false"
                                    Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                            <WaterMeterData Index="151.356" IndexCheck="0"
                                            ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1"
                                            ConsumptionTolerance="0"
                                            ConsumptionMin="0"
                                            ConsumptionMax="0"/>
                        </WaterMeter>
                    </Meters>
                </Customer>
                <Customer ID="5" BillingCode=""
                          FirstName="AVENIDA CENTRAL LT243 P2 DRT FR"
                          LastName="" Address="ALICE MELO COSTA"
                          PostalCode="486647" City="" Created="false"
                          Modified="false">
                    <Meters>
                        <WaterMeter ID="5" BillingCode=""
                                    ReadingDate="2023-06-27T14:04:08"
                                    ReadingType="1" ReadingMode="1"
                                    ReadingStatus="2" NbWheels="8"
                                    EnergyType="0" UnitType="0"
                                    SerialNumber="12LA056712"
                                    ReadSerialNumber="12LA056712"
                                    SerialNumberCheck="1" FreeMessage=""
                                    FileNumber="4" Created="false"
                                    Modified="false" IsMeterHardToRead="false">
                            <WaterMeterData Index="344.635" IndexCheck="0"
                                            ConsumptionCheckFlag="-1"
                                            ConsumptionTolerance="0"
                                            ConsumptionMin="0"
                                            ConsumptionMax="0"/>
                        </WaterMeter>
                    </Meters>
                </Customer>
            </Customers>
        </RouteData>
    </Route>
</ActarisEasyRoutes>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('(Meters/WaterMeter/@ReadingDate)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS ReadingDate
    , c.value('@PostalCode', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS PostalCode
    , c.value('(Meters/WaterMeter/WaterMeterData/@Index)[1]', 'DECIMAL(18, 2)') AS Leitura
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/ActarisEasyRoutes/Route/RouteData/Customers/Customer') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| ReadingDate | PostalCode | Leitura |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-27 14:04:07.000 | 1337602 | 326.63 |
| 2023-06-27 14:04:07.000 | 1319337 | 538.16 |
| 2023-06-27 14:04:07.000 | 442569 | 213.48 |
| 2023-06-27 14:04:08.000 | 526193 | 151.36 |
| 2023-06-27 14:04:08.000 | 486647 | 344.64 |