# Import large XML file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have another XML file with 132812 lines and after loading 2874 records into SQL, but is very slower to import. If I have only 10 records, it is very fast.

I have also a problem on line 2:

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
```

doesn't work but

```
<Document>
```

works.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>0</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2020-04-17T04:12:58</CreDtTm>
        </GrpHdr>
        <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
            <OrgnlMsgId>0</OrgnlMsgId>
            <OrgnlMsgNmId>pain.008.001.02</OrgnlMsgNmId>
            <OrgnlNbOfTxs>2874</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
            <OrgnlCtrlSum>0.59</OrgnlCtrlSum>
            <StsRsnInf>
                <Rsn>
                    <Prtry>M001</Prtry>
                </Rsn>
            </StsRsnInf>
            <NbOfTxsPerSts>
                <DtldNbOfTxs>1565</DtldNbOfTxs>
                <DtldSts>RJCT</DtldSts>
                <DtldCtrlSum>74317.84</DtldCtrlSum>
            </NbOfTxsPerSts>
        </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
        <OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
            <OrgnlPmtInfId>01-10-1-RCUR</OrgnlPmtInfId>
            <OrgnlNbOfTxs>2874</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
            <OrgnlCtrlSum>91756.59</OrgnlCtrlSum>
            <StsRsnInf>
                <Rsn>
                    <Prtry>L001</Prtry>
                </Rsn>
            </StsRsnInf>
            <NbOfTxsPerSts>
                <DtldNbOfTxs>1565</DtldNbOfTxs>
                <DtldSts>RJCT</DtldSts>
                <DtldCtrlSum>0.84</DtldCtrlSum>
            </NbOfTxsPerSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>301</StsId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>01,FTR,2020,114175</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <StsRsnInf>
                    <Rsn>
                        <Cd>0000</Cd>
                    </Rsn>
                </StsRsnInf>
                <AcctSvcrRef>0</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">9.24</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdColltnDt>2020-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
                    <CdtrSchmeId>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>0</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrSchmeId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                        <CtgyPurp>
                            <Cd>WTER</Cd>
                        </CtgyPurp>
                    </PmtTpInf>
                    <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
                    <MndtRltdInf>
                        <MndtId>0</MndtId>
                        <DtOfSgntr>2010-10-18</DtOfSgntr>
                    </MndtRltdInf>
                    <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>Fatura Consumo Abastecimento de Agua</Ustrd>
                    </RmtInf>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Nm>Joaquim Cunha Silva</Nm>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </DbtrAcct>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>0</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                            <AdrLine>0</AdrLine>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrAcct>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>301</StsId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>01,FTR,2020,114180</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <StsRsnInf>
                    <Rsn>
                        <Cd>0000</Cd>
                    </Rsn>
                </StsRsnInf>
                <AcctSvcrRef>0</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">9.90</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdColltnDt>2020-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
                    <CdtrSchmeId>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>0</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrSchmeId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                        <CtgyPurp>
                            <Cd>WTER</Cd>
                        </CtgyPurp>
                    </PmtTpInf>
                    <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
                    <MndtRltdInf>
                        <MndtId>0</MndtId>
                        <DtOfSgntr>2011-08-19</DtOfSgntr>
                    </MndtRltdInf>
                    <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>Fatura Consumo Abastecimento de Agua</Ustrd>
                    </RmtInf>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Nm>Teresa Jesus Silva Cerqueira</Nm>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </DbtrAcct>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>0</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                            <AdrLine>0</AdrLine>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrAcct>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>301</StsId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>01,FTR,2020,114169</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <StsRsnInf>
                    <Rsn>
                        <Cd>0000</Cd>
                    </Rsn>
                </StsRsnInf>
                <AcctSvcrRef>0</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">8.23</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdColltnDt>2020-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
                    <CdtrSchmeId>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>0</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrSchmeId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                        <CtgyPurp>
                            <Cd>WTER</Cd>
                        </CtgyPurp>
                    </PmtTpInf>
                    <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
                    <MndtRltdInf>
                        <MndtId>0</MndtId>
                        <DtOfSgntr>2014-10-30</DtOfSgntr>
                    </MndtRltdInf>
                    <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>Fatura Consumo Abastecimento de Agua</Ustrd>
                    </RmtInf>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Nm>Manuel Fernando Rocha Braga</Nm>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </DbtrAcct>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>0</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                            <AdrLine>0</AdrLine>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrAcct>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>301</StsId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>01,FTR,2020,114173</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <StsRsnInf>
                    <Rsn>
                        <Cd>0000</Cd>
                    </Rsn>
                </StsRsnInf>
                <AcctSvcrRef>0</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">5.42</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdColltnDt>2020-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
                    <CdtrSchmeId>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>0</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrSchmeId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                        <CtgyPurp>
                            <Cd>WTER</Cd>
                        </CtgyPurp>
                    </PmtTpInf>
                    <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
                    <MndtRltdInf>
                        <MndtId>0</MndtId>
                        <DtOfSgntr>2008-10-20</DtOfSgntr>
                    </MndtRltdInf>
                    <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>Fatura Consumo Abastecimento de Agua</Ustrd>
                    </RmtInf>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Nm>Manuel Goncalves Amorim</Nm>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </DbtrAcct>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>0</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                            <AdrLine>0</AdrLine>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrAcct>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>301</StsId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>01,FTR,2020,114174</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <StsRsnInf>
                    <Rsn>
                        <Cd>0000</Cd>
                    </Rsn>
                </StsRsnInf>
                <AcctSvcrRef>0</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">9.24</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdColltnDt>2020-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
                    <CdtrSchmeId>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>0</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrSchmeId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                        <CtgyPurp>
                            <Cd>WTER</Cd>
                        </CtgyPurp>
                    </PmtTpInf>
                    <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
                    <MndtRltdInf>
                        <MndtId>0</MndtId>
                        <DtOfSgntr>2008-10-20</DtOfSgntr>
                    </MndtRltdInf>
                    <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>Fatura Consumo Abastecimento de Agua</Ustrd>
                    </RmtInf>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Nm>Manuel Antonio Goncalves Oliveira</Nm>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </DbtrAcct>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>0</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                            <AdrLine>0</AdrLine>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrAcct>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>301</StsId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>01,FTR,2020,114165</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <StsRsnInf>
                    <Rsn>
                        <Cd>0000</Cd>
                    </Rsn>
                </StsRsnInf>
                <AcctSvcrRef>0</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">5.42</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdColltnDt>2020-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
                    <CdtrSchmeId>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>0</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrSchmeId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                        <CtgyPurp>
                            <Cd>WTER</Cd>
                        </CtgyPurp>
                    </PmtTpInf>
                    <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
                    <MndtRltdInf>
                        <MndtId>0</MndtId>
                        <DtOfSgntr>2015-08-18</DtOfSgntr>
                    </MndtRltdInf>
                    <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>Fatura Consumo Abastecimento de Agua</Ustrd>
                    </RmtInf>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Nm>Manuel Fernandes Neiva</Nm>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </DbtrAcct>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>0</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                            <AdrLine>R 0</AdrLine>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrAcct>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>301</StsId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>01,FTR,2020,114242</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <StsRsnInf>
                    <Rsn>
                        <Cd>0000</Cd>
                    </Rsn>
                </StsRsnInf>
                <AcctSvcrRef>0</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="EUR">5.42</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdColltnDt>2020-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
                    <CdtrSchmeId>
                        <Id>
                            <PrvtId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>0</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </PrvtId>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrSchmeId>
                    <PmtTpInf>
                        <SvcLvl>
                            <Cd>SEPA</Cd>
                        </SvcLvl>
                        <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                        <CtgyPurp>
                            <Cd>WTER</Cd>
                        </CtgyPurp>
                    </PmtTpInf>
                    <PmtMtd>DD</PmtMtd>
                    <MndtRltdInf>
                        <MndtId>0</MndtId>
                        <DtOfSgntr>2008-10-20</DtOfSgntr>
                    </MndtRltdInf>
                    <RmtInf>
                        <Ustrd>Fatura Consumo Abastecimento de Agua</Ustrd>
                    </RmtInf>
                    <Dbtr>
                        <Nm>Manuel Jose Costa Goncalves</Nm>
                    </Dbtr>
                    <DbtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </DbtrAcct>
                    <DbtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </DbtrAgt>
                    <CdtrAgt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>0</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </CdtrAgt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>0</Nm>
                        <PstlAdr>
                            <Ctry>PT</Ctry>
                            <AdrLine>0</AdrLine>
                        </PstlAdr>
                    </Cdtr>
                    <CdtrAcct>
                        <Id>
                            <IBAN>0</IBAN>
                        </Id>
                    </CdtrAcct>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
        </OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
    </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

And my SQL code is:

```
WITH rs (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\temp\agu\bancos.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
-- INSERT INTO dbo.Import_Oase (StationID, TransactionTimestamp, TicketNumber, Mileage)
SELECT c.value('(StsId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS StationID
    , c.value('(OrgnlEndToEndId/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS TransactionTimestamp
    ,c.value('(StsRsnInf/Rsn/Cd/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as umdois
    ,c.value('(AcctSvcrRef/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as Iban
    ,c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/Amt/InstdAmt/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as asjds
    ,c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/Dbtr/Nm/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as asjds
    ,c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/DbtrAcct/Id/IBAN/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as iban2
    /*,c.value('OrgnlTxRef/Dbtr/Nm/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as dinheiro*/
   /* , c.value('(TransactionInfo/TicketNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS TicketNumber
    , c.value('(TransactionInfo/CustomerInput/Mileage/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Mileage*/
FROM rs 
   CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/Document/CstmrPmtStsRpt/OrgnlPmtInfAndSts/TxInfAndSts') AS t(c);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What about your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76689571/import-all-xml-into-sql Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, it was two questions even!

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

Your XML has a default namespace. It needs a special handling via **XMLNAMESPACES()** clause.

**SQL #1**

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03')
    , rs (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\temp\agu\bancos.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
-- INSERT INTO dbo.Import_Oase (StationID, TransactionTimestamp, TicketNumber, Mileage)
SELECT c.value('(StsId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS StationID
    , c.value('(OrgnlEndToEndId/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS TransactionTimestamp
    ,c.value('(StsRsnInf/Rsn/Cd/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as umdois
    ,c.value('(AcctSvcrRef/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as Iban
    ,c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/Amt/InstdAmt/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as asjds
    ,c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/Dbtr/Nm/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as asjds
    ,c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/DbtrAcct/Id/IBAN/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as iban2
FROM rs 
   CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/Document/CstmrPmtStsRpt/OrgnlPmtInfAndSts/TxInfAndSts') AS t(c);
```

**SQL #2**

Here is much more performant method. Give it a shot.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XmlColumn XML
);

INSERT INTO @tbl(XmlColumn)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\temp\agu\bancos.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03')
SELECT c.value('(StsId/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS StationID
    , c.value('(OrgnlEndToEndId/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS TransactionTimestamp
    , c.value('(StsRsnInf/Rsn/Cd/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as umdois
    , c.value('(AcctSvcrRef/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as Iban
    , c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/Amt/InstdAmt/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as asjds
    , c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/Dbtr/Nm/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as asjds
    , c.value('(OrgnlTxRef/DbtrAcct/Id/IBAN/text())[1]','varchar(50)') as iban2
FROM @tbl 
CROSS APPLY XmlColumn.nodes('/Document/CstmrPmtStsRpt/OrgnlPmtInfAndSts/TxInfAndSts') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| StationID | TransactionTimestamp | umdois | Iban | asjds | asjds | iban2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 301 | 01,FTR,2020,114175 | 0000 | 0 | 9.24 | Joaquim Cunha Silva | 0 |
| 301 | 01,FTR,2020,114180 | 0000 | 0 | 9.90 | Teresa Jesus Silva Cerqueira | 0 |
| 301 | 01,FTR,2020,114169 | 0000 | 0 | 8.23 | Manuel Fernando Rocha Braga | 0 |
| 301 | 01,FTR,2020,114173 | 0000 | 0 | 5.42 | Manuel Goncalves Amorim | 0 |
| 301 | 01,FTR,2020,114174 | 0000 | 0 | 9.24 | Manuel Antonio Goncalves Oliveira | 0 |
| 301 | 01,FTR,2020,114165 | 0000 | 0 | 5.42 | Manuel Fernandes Neiva | 0 |
| 301 | 01,FTR,2020,114242 | 0000 | 0 | 5.42 | Manuel Jose Costa Goncalves | 0 |

Comment: It takes 1m:30 seconds to open 30 records. It's very slow

Comment: I updated the answer with the **SQL #2**. Check it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with powershell to see if it is faster.  Usse Invoke-sqlcmd : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps

Use following to parse the xml

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
$ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
$TxInfAndSts = $doc.Descendants($ns + 'TxInfAndSts')

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($TxInfAndSt in $TxInfAndSts)
{
   $StationID = $TxInfAndSt.Descendants($ns + 'StsId')[0].Value
   $TransactionTimestamp = $TxInfAndSt.Descendants($ns + 'OrgnlEndToEndId')[0].Value
   $umdois = $TxInfAndSt.Descendants($ns + 'Cd')[0].VAlue
   $Iban = $TxInfAndSt.Descendants($ns + 'AcctSvcrRef')[0].Value
   $asjds = $TxInfAndSt.Descendants($ns + 'InstdAmt')[0].Value
   $iban2 = $TxInfAndSt.Descendants($ns + 'IBAN')[0].Value 

   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
    StationID = $StationID
    TransactionTimestamp  = $TransactionTimestamp
    umdois = $umdois
    Iban = $Iban
    asjds = $asjds
    iban2 = $iban2
   }
   $table.Add($newRow)
}
$table
```

Comment: I don't have the System.Xml.Linq there is another way to do it

Comment: It is built into powershell.  Powsershell is written in c# and the net library is installed in PS automatically, but you have to use the full namespace of the method like in my code. 
 Just paste code into PS and it should work.

Comment: Unable to find type [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument].
At line:3 char:8
+ $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Xml.Linq.XDocument:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ $ns = $doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: The using statement has to be at top of module.  You are not getting an error on the using statement which either means you left the using statement out of the module or the library was found.  You would get a load error on the using statement if the library was not found.